# Create same object multiple times in different function or use single instance?

Tags: android

I am creating `AlertDialog.Builder` to display user whether data is available or not, entry is deleted or not etc. I am confused about creating object in `onCreate()` method or creating local object of `AlertDialog.Builder` in function. Which one is optimal?

I guess  creating a single object in o`nCreate()` because it located once memory from heap  and it required throughout `Activity` . Am I correct or not?

```
//This Alert Dialog use for various button .That's why we building single Object only
AlertDialog.Builder  buidler  = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will reuse the instance of `AlertDialog.Builder` you should create it one time in `onCreate()` and re-use it when needed. Otherwise, create it when needed.

Comment: I concerned with memory usage(or management) . Allocating or Deallocating memory again  and again is optimal approach or allocating once for activity.

Comment: In your case is best to allocate in activity.